# How to find a specific number in a string Java

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to search a string for a certain number then if that number exists in the string do the following:

```
String str = "String4";
int myInt = 0;
public static void checkString(String str)  // FIX ME
{
    if(str.indexOf('3') == 0)
    {
        myInt = 3;
    }
    else if(str.indexOf('4') == 0)
    {
        myInt = 4;
    }
    else if(str.indexOf('5') == 0)
    {
        myInt = 5;
    }
}
```

This never returns true though, is there an alternative way to search the string. There is a lot of extra code, but this method is the only thing causing the problem. I am pulling my hair out because of it, some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try using string.contains('4') instead

Comment: do you know the `integer` you're searching for before-hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
if(str.indexOf('3') == 0)
```

search everytime 3 at position 0, it's not appropriate, because digit can be everywhere in string.

Use instead

```
str.indexOf('3')!=-1
```

and retrieve position with return value of indexOf

Answer (score 1):

Check if a substring is in the given string using the `contains` method.

```
public static void checkString(String str)
{
    if(str.contains("3"))
        myInt = 3;
    else if(str.contains("4"))
        myInt = 4;
    else if(str.contains("5"))
        myInt = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with an explanation of your approach before we get to an answer.

Starting with your string `String str = "String4"`, I'm assuming that you pass it to `checkString()`.

The `indexOf()` function for a string searches the string for a substring (a character in your case) and returns its position, indexed from 0. For example, if you call `str.indexOf("t")` it will return 1 because the character `t` is in position 1. Therefore, in your code you check if the numbers 3, 4, and 5 reside in the strings index 0 (the first character).

If you want to use `indexOf()` for this function, you can check if the number is in the string in the first place. `IndexOf()` returns `-1` if the character your searching for isn't in the string, so you can use the following:

```
if (str.indexOf("3") != -1){
    //do your stuff
}
```

And the same for 4 and 5.